# Angularjs/javascript ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've started to learn angularjs not that much time ago. And I'm about to write some form application. The thing is that when I'm trying to output default value from select and some datepicker (got it from twitter bootstrap) into the table, it doesn't appear when page is loaded. Also, when I change date on datepicker it still doesn't appear in the table but if I change select options it appears. So how can I fix it? I need to output datepicker value when I change it + output default values when page is loaded. 
Here's Datetimepicker

```
<label> <b> * Date and Time of Incident: </b> </label>
<div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
<input type="datetime" ng-model="date" name="date" required></input>
<span class="add-on">
<i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
</span>
</div>
```

Here's random input:

```
<label> <b> * Reported By: </b> </label> <input type="text" name="report" ng- model="report"  required / >
```

When I use: {{report}} - it shows what I've been entered, but if I use {{date}} it doesn't show anything, only If I write something manually, but I want disable this field for users so he can only choose dates\time.

Comment: Can you give us more code? Have you got controller and scope?

Comment: I didn't even use controller and scope, does it really necessary? I can give all my html if u want, but it's big.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NKyps/2/

Here's my code. I couldn't add datepicker there but I think if you can help me with last 3 inputs that depends on Well-select I'll realize what's wrong with datepicker. The question is: why there's no default options when its loaded, and why I don't see them when I use their ng-model id, works for other inputs. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date. It's datepicker written as angular directive. You can find plenty of useful angular utils, modules and directives here: http://angular-ui.github.io/.

Comment: the thing is that I need exactly DateTimepicker =( + I used Twitter bootstrap 4 design.

Comment: bootstrap version is currently 2, the 3rd will come in a couple of weeks ( as per July 2013 ). Not sure how you can use bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think the problem is that Angular doesn't know about that change. For this you should call $scope.$digest() or make the change inside of $scope.$apply(function() { $()... }); But you need a controller for that.

[Here are an example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/agvTz/39/)

Or you can use the "oficial" calendar for angular: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar

Cheers!